# how to change font of android webView with javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

first, i'm not a so familiar with `javascript` but i need to use it.

what i need is to change the font of `webView` in android after loading web page,

so in `onPageFinished()` i call the `javascript` code.

i know this code can change the font:

`loadurl("javascript:(function(){document.body.style.fontFamily='\"Courier New\", Courier, monospace';})()");`

it works fine and font get changed, but what i want is to apply my custom font from asset.

i tried something like this:

`loadurl("javascript:(function(){document.body.style.fontFamily= \"src: url('file:///android_asset/byekan.ttf')\";})()");`

and other things similar to this, without any success.

so anyone can help me to apply my custom font after loading a page in android webview?

**note**: the html is from an output source (it's not local) so i can not add any css style to it.

Answer (score -1):

you can put below code in your html file

```
<style>
        /** Specify a font named "MyFont",
            and specify the URL where it can be found: */
        @font-face {
          font-family: "MyFont";
          src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/BLKCHCRY.TTF');
        }
        h3 { font-family:"MyFont"}  
</style>
```

or later by "wv.loadUrl" set font for any element

Comment: the html page is not local, so i can not add anything to it. i'm sure that the website has it's own css style, and i think loading the style you specified gives me a black screen.

Comment: you can create style tag by javascript and add it to html page

Comment: ok, i tried this `loadUrl("javascript:(function(){var newStyle=document.createElement('style'); newStyle.appendChild(document.createTextNode(\"@font-face{font-family:'byekan'; src:url('file:///android_asset/byekan.ttf')}\")); document.head.appendChild(newStyle); document.body.style.fontFamily = \"byekan, serif\";})()")` and i get this error: `Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/byekan.ttf at null:0` . any idea?